# Swapping two values within a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am currently working on a 15 puzzle programming assignment. My question here is about how I would go about swapping the empty tile with an adjacent tile.

So, for example, let's go with the initial setup board. 
I have:

```
int originalBoard[4][4] = {
              {1 , 2, 3, 4},
              {5 , 6, 7, 8},
              {9 ,10,11,12},
              {13,14,15, 0}};
```

So here, the locations of 12, 15, and 0 (the empty tile) in the array are [3][4], [4][3], and [4][4] respectively. What would be a method of swapping 0 out with either 12 or 15?

What I had in mind for this was creating a loop that would keep track of the empty tile every time I made a move.

I believe an optimal method would be to have two functions. 1 that would update the location of the empty tile, and 1 to make the move.

So, right off the top of my head I would have:

```
void locateEmptyTile(int& blankRow, int& blankColumn, int originalBoard[4][4])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
        {
            if (originalBoard[row][col] == 0)
            {
                blankRow = row;
                blankColumn = col;
            }
        }
    }
}

void move(int& blankRow, int& blankColumn, int originalBoard[4][4])
{

}
```

And in my `main` function I would have the variables: `int blankRow` and `int blankColumn`

Now, how would I take that data from `locateEmptyTile` and apply it into the `move` function in the relevant practical manner? The process does not currently connect within my head.

I appreciate any little bits of help.

Comment: Be careful with your indexing. C++ arrays are zero-based so your locations [3][4], [4][3] are not what you think they are, and [4][4] is out of bounds..

Comment: From the result of `locateEmptyTile` you will have 2, 3 or 4 possible adjacent cells to swap with. You should calculate those possible targets for swapping. Then have the `move` method take two cells locations to swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic swap concept (pre-C++11) is hold a temporary variable. Simply...

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void swap(T& lhs, U& rhs) {
    T t = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = t;
}
```

So, you don't need to reference `blankRow` and `blankCol`, you just need to reference the values on the grid. Lets say that you want to swap what you know is blank positioned at `(2, 1)` with `(2, 2)`...

```
swap(originalBoard[2][1], originalBoard[2][2]);
```

... will swap the values *within* `originalBoard`.

If you are using C++11 or later, just use `std::swap()` to swap positions. That's exactly what it does.

If you would like `originalBoard` to be immutable an result in a totally different board, just copy it first before applying the switch.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just asking for swap function you can use [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

```
#include <algorithm> // until c++11
#include <utility> // since c++11

...
int m[3][3];
...
//somewhere in the code
std::swap(m[i][j], m[j][i]); // this swaps contents of two matrix cells
...
```

Or you can just write where you want to swap contents of two variables (in example int a and int b):

```
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

As you can see swapping is the same as with normal arrays, c++ does not know if you are swapping two matrix cells or two array elements, it just knows that you are swapping two memory blocks with certain type.